# Do I need to recite the duas before entering and exiting toilet/washroom if I am going for bathing only?

Tags: dua, muslim-practices

I am a revert to Deen e Islam. I wanted to know if I had to recite the duas before entering and exiting toilet/washroom if I am just going to bath and not relieve myself.

Answer (score 1):

It is sunnah to read the respective duas before entering and after exiting the toilets/washrooms.

I assume you have a single enclosure that has both your bath and lavatories fixtures. Hence, it is considered one of the places mentioned in the below Hadith:

> حَدَّثَنَا مُسَدَّدُ بْنُ مُسَرْهَدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا حَمَّادُ بْنُ زَيْدٍ،
>   وَعَبْدُ الْوَارِثِ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الْعَزِيزِ بْنِ صُهَيْبٍ، عَنْ أَنَسِ
>   بْنِ مَالِكٍ، قَالَ كَانَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم إِذَا
>   دَخَلَ الْخَلاَءَ - قَالَ عَنْ حَمَّادٍ قَالَ ‏"‏ اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي
>   أَعُوذُ بِكَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ وَقَالَ عَنْ عَبْدِ الْوَارِثِ - قَالَ ‏"‏
>   أَعُوذُ بِاللَّهِ مِنَ الْخُبُثِ وَالْخَبَائِثِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو
>   دَاوُد رَوَاهُ شُعْبَةُ عَنْ عَبْدِ الْعَزِيزِ اللَّهُمَّ إِنِّي
>   أَعُوذُ بِكَ وَقَالَ مَرَّةً أَعُوذُ بِاللَّهِ و قَالَ وُهَيْبٌ
>   فَلْيَتَعَوَّذْ بِاللَّهِ
>
> When the Apostle of Allah (SAW) entered the
>   toilet, he used to say (before entering): "O Allah, I seek refuge in
>   Thee." This is according to the version of Hammad. 'Abd al-Warith has
>   another version :"I seek refuge in Allaah from male and female
>   devils."
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawud 4](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/1/4)

Also in another Hadith:

> حَدَّثَنَا عَمْرُو بْنُ مَرْزُوقٍ، أَخْبَرَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ
>   قَتَادَةَ، عَنِ النَّضْرِ بْنِ أَنَسٍ، عَنْ زَيْدِ بْنِ أَرْقَمَ، عَنْ
>   رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّ هَذِهِ الْحُشُوشَ
>   مُحْتَضَرَةٌ فَإِذَا أَتَى أَحَدُكُمُ الْخَلاَءَ فَلْيَقُلْ أَعُوذُ
>   بِاللَّهِ مِنَ الْخُبُثِ وَالْخَبَائِثِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> Narrated Zayd ibn Arqam:
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: **These privies are frequented by the
>   jinns and devils**. So when anyone amongst you goes there, he should
>   say: "I seek refuge in Allah from male and female devils."
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawud 6](https://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/1/6)

In earlier times, lavatories were not part of the main house. They were considered impure and build in the outside compound. With the ever increasing shortage of space and abundance of apartment system ***we now even have attached washrooms for our bedrooms.***

May God give us all hidayah and protect us from evil. Ameen.